# TFS (Azure DevOps) On prem upgrade 2018 to 2019 question

Tags: tfs

I have just finished upgrading my TFS Server from 2015 to 2018 and all is working well.  I would like to now upgrade to TFS 2019 (Azure DevOps Server), however, all of the instructions I can find are rather disjointed.

Does anyone have a link to a step-by-step guide or something like that?

Since I have no customizations, I was assuming it was more of just a matter of running the installer on the DVD image and following the instructions.

Am I right in assuming one does not have to run the configuration wizard anymore?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First please pay attention to Requirements for [Azure DevOps on-premises](https://blog.codeinside.eu/2019/04/30/update-onprem-tfs-2018-to-azuredevops-server-2019/). Make sure your hardware already meet all requirements for Azure DevOps 2019.

For example:

[image]

If your setup is one server for the “Application Tier” and another SQL database server for the “Data Tier”.  It's same with the environment if you put them in only one physical machine/server.

Since the “Data Tier” was already running with SQL Server 2016 (or above) on TFS 2018, so you **only needed to upgrade the “Application Tier”**.

During the server configuration wizard, you could directly configure the production upgrade.

Here is a blog with step-by-step tutorial and screenshot, please kind refer it-- [Update OnPrem TFS 2018 to AzureDevOps Server 2019](https://blog.codeinside.eu/2019/04/30/update-onprem-tfs-2018-to-azuredevops-server-2019/)

Comment: thanks.  I am on Win Sever 2016/SQLServer 2017 (App and Data Tier on same machine).  Installation looks the same as previous one.

Comment: One question, is there a need to delete/configure the search server again, or does the newer installer realize it is installed and work with the existing setup?

Comment: @AndyW Thanks for your kindly response. In my mind, no need to do this. During configuration wizard, it includes updated Search components under  existing deployment . And it include basic authentication for the communication between the TFS and Search service to make it more secure. Any user upgrade  will need to provide credentials as part of configuring Search feature through Server configuration wizard. Also found an official link for your refer: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/administration?view=azure-devops#upgrade-search-in-azure-devops-server-and-tfs